# C++ static array in method

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, function, static

One can use static array in method for performance if the method frequently called like

```
static char [1024];
```

What I want to ask is , if the array size is small like 128 or 64 which one is more advantageous from the samples one and two.
Sample 1:

```
void foo(){
    static  mArr char[128];
    memset(mArr,0x0,128);//not sure if this line is necessary but I think its a must ,     any commends appriciated.
}
```

Sample 2:

```
void foo(){
    char mArr[128];
}
```

Comment: Instead of the `memset()` initialize your array only **once**: `char mArr[128]{0};`

Comment: Yes but when the array is static only at the first call array is created , for other calles new array not allocated and its uses previous one in that case is array data dumb ? If this is the case your answer may not work  i think.

Comment: `static` means the array is persistent over different function calls. So for the next call the memory is not garbage, but contains the data from the previous call.

Comment: "which one is more advantageous " - Advantageous *for what* ? They do entirely different things. The former has static linkage, clears `mArr` with each entry, and is not thread-safe. The latter is automatic and indeterminate on entry. *What problem are you trying to solve?* Performance? write to, and read from, memory as little as possible. Of the two, #2 will *clearly* "perform" better, since it does nothing.

Comment: Measure, don't guess. (Any potential saving is imo more than offset by the loss of thread safety).

Comment: I'm also somewhat confounded by the number of answers that are zero-initializing the already-zero-initialized `static` array. (it is, after all, static).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little actual difference, the latter basicly just adds 128 to the stack-pointer.
if you only **must** do the clearing at first run, there can be a saving in:

```
static char mArr[128] = {0} ;
```

the `memset` is only necessary if the array is need to be zeroed-out every time, there's nothing 'magic' with static;

Comment: But for my case array should be zeroed at every call , in that case is your answer still valid ?

Comment: if you want clearing every time, remove `static`. Or use your own Sample 1. Your Sample 2 don't clear anything, and might use uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 2):

Sample 3:

```
void foo() {
    char mArr[128] = {0};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Version 1:**

```
void foo() {
  static char a[128];
  memset(a,0x0,128);
  // use a
}
```

Allocates `a` on the *heap* and provides memory which is persistent over all function calls. `a` works a bit like a global variable with all the problems of global variables. For example, this version will be problematic if the function is called from multiple threads.

---

**Version 2:**

```
void foo() {
  char a[128] = {0};
  // use a
}
```

Allocates `a` on the *stack* each time the function is called. `={0}` initializes with `0` ( every time the function is called). Use this if you do not need the memory to be persistent over several function calls.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely sample 2 - sample 1 would not compile (first char, then variable name ;)

Anyway, static means the array is set on a fixed position in memory while in sample 2 the array is put on the stack. This is not about advantageous - it's about what you need.

Use 1) if you want to call foo more than once and you always want to use the same array and it should keep it's contents between the calls (without the memset).

Use 2) if you want to use the array just in this function and have a "fresh" array every time you call it.

You do not need the memset - it would just clear the array every time you call foo. While that may be a good thing, it definitely is pointless in combination with static, except you do:

```
void foo()
{
    static  mArr char[128];
    static bool firstrun = true;
    if(firstrun)
    {
        memset(mArr,0x0,128);
        firstrun = false;
    }
}
```

In this case, firstrun would be used to initialize your function at the first run and leave it as is in the following runs.

For using "static" have a look at [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/c-static-variables-functions/) article.

Answer (score -1):

I would choose Sample 1 but you maybe need to reconsider memset.

Lets review these senarios:

a) You need to empty the array each time foo() is called.

b) You do not need to empty the array each time foo() is called.

For a:

```
void foo()
{
    char mArr[128] = {0};
}
```

For b:

```
void foo()
{
    static mArr[128] = {0};
}
```